# Xamarin ListView not showing content

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I'm trying to create an app using Xamarin forms and one of the pages is a ListView. I need to bind it to an ObservableCollection, that gets its values from the Azure SQL but the binding is failing. The Observable collection does get populated from the Web API so I'm not sure where the problem is. Any help is appreciated!

xaml page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:SiteVisits.ViewModels" xmlns:model="clr-namespace:SiteVisits.Models" 
             x:DataType="viewModel:AllWellsViewModel"
             x:Class="SiteVisits.Views.AllWells">


    <ListView x:Name="WellsCollection"
                ItemsSource="{Binding WellsCollection}"
                HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Padding="10" x:DataType="model:Well">
                         <Label Text="{Binding Description}" 
                                        FontSize="Large"
                                        VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

xaml.cs :

```
  public partial class AllWells : ContentPage
    {
        AllWellsViewModel viewModel;

        public AllWells(AllWellsViewModel viewModel)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.viewModel = viewModel;
            BindingContext = this.viewModel;
        }

        public AllWells()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            viewModel = new AllWellsViewModel();
            BindingContext = viewModel;
        }
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
  public class AllWellsViewModel : BaseViewModel 
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Well> WellsCollection { get; set; }

        public AllWellsViewModel() 
        {
            Title = "Browse";
            WellsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Well>();
            InitializeData();

        }
        async void InitializeData()
        {
            var wellDataStore = new WellDataStore();

            var wells = await wellDataStore.GetAllWells();
            if (wells != null)
            {
                WellsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Well>(wells);
            }
        }
    }
```

Model:

```
    public class Well
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public string Description { get; set; } 
    }
```

Comment: you are initializing `WellsCollection` twice, and you are calling an async method from your constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jason commented, the problem is that you are not waiting for the result from Azure.

So call the `InitializeData` method from page's `OnAppearing` instead of vm's constructor.

### AllWellsViewModel.cs

```
    public class AllWellsViewModel : BaseViewModel 
    {
        public AllWellsViewModel() 
        {
            Title = "Browse";
            WellsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Well>();
            //remove the method call here
        }
    }
```

### AllWells.xaml.cs

```
public partial class AllWells : ContentPage
{
    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        //call the method here instead and "AWAIT"
        await vm.InitializeData();
    }
}
```

Plus, also apply Gerald's answer for improvement.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a `ObservableCollection` you should only create a new one once, else the reference to whatever you are binding it too will be lost and you need to set it again. Just initialize the collection once and clear/fill it each time.

```cs
async void InitializeData()
{
  var wellDataStore = new WellDataStore();

  var wells = await wellDataStore.GetAllWells();
  if (wells != null)
  {
    WellsCollection.Clear();

    foreach (var well in wells)
    {
      WellsCollection.Add(well);
    }
  }
}
```

Also the double constructor of your page looks a bit funny. I think you should only keep the one that has the view model as a parameter.